# Issue with using Quartz2 plugin in Grails 2.4.5

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-2.4

Quarrtz2 Plugin I Used : `compile ":quartz2:2.1.6.2"`

> Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation
>   of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException:
>   Class not found loading Grails application: resources
>
> Caused by ClassNotFoundException: resources
>   ->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1

Comment: did you try to clean the project and build again?

Comment: yes i did clean, but still no luck

Comment: This is Fixed. Here Quartz2 looking for [resources.groovy] in config without package, but in Grails 2.4.5 this class Packaged with [spring.resources.groovy]